# How do we turn an image into a background for a window using PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, background, pysimplegui

I want to make the following image the background for an app me and my friend are trying to make. However, we tried multiple methods and none succeeded.

We tried various methods, looking on youtube and Stack Overflow.

Here's our code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
window = sg.Window(title="Cobalt", layout=[[]], margins=(487, 245)).read()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, tkinter code used for it, not tested for all elements.
It may need different code for different layout at this moment.
All Frames and Columns will be filled background image too here.

Need more tkinter programming experience for it.

```py
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def image_to_data(im):

    with BytesIO() as output:
        im.save(output, format="PNG")
        data = output.getvalue()
    return data

def make_background(window, file, main_frame):

    global images

    def find_frames(widget):
        widgets = list(widget.children.values())
        if isinstance(widget, (sg.tk.Frame, sg.tk.LabelFrame)):
            widget.update()
            x, y = widget.winfo_rootx() - x0, widget.winfo_rooty() - y0
            width, height = widget.winfo_width(), widget.winfo_height()
            new_im = im_.crop((x, y, x+width, y+height))
            image = sg.tk.PhotoImage(data=image_to_data(new_im))
            images.append(image)
            label = sg.tk.Label(widget, image=image, padx=0, pady=0, bd=0, bg=bg)
            label.place(x=0, y=0)
            label.lower()
        for widget in widgets:
            find_frames(widget)

    size = window.size
    im_ = Image.open(file).resize(size)
    root = window.TKroot
    widgets = list(root.children.values())
    x0, y0 = root.winfo_rootx(), root.winfo_rooty()

    frame = sg.tk.Frame(root, padx=0, pady=0, bd=0, bg=bg)
    frame.place(x=0, y=0)
    images = []
    image = sg.tk.PhotoImage(data=image_to_data(im_))
    images.append(image)
    label = sg.tk.Label(frame, image=image, padx=0, pady=0, bd=0, bg=bg)
    label.pack()
    main_frame.Widget.master.place(in_=frame, anchor='center', relx=.5, rely=.5)
    frame.lower()
    frame.update()
    for widget in widgets:
        find_frames(widget)

bg = sg.theme_background_color()
background_image_file = 'd:/background.png'
w, h = size = 640, 480  # size of background image

sg.set_options(dpi_awareness=True)

frame = [
    [sg.Input(size=(30, 1), expand_x=True),
     sg.Button('Browse')],
    [sg.Multiline('', expand_x=True, expand_y=True)],
    [sg.Button('Exit')],
]
# Need only one frame here to move it to center of window
layout = [[sg.Frame('', frame, size=(350, 200), border_width=0, key='FRAME', background_color=bg)]]

location = sg.Window.get_screen_size()
window = sg.Window('Background Demo', layout, margins=(0, 0), grab_anywhere=True,
    size=size, keep_on_top=True, finalize=True,
    no_titlebar=True,
    transparent_color=bg,
)

images = []
make_background(window, background_image_file, window['FRAME'])

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Cancel', 'Exit'):
        break
    print(event)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: The PySimpleGUIQt version supports background images.  The tkinter version is much more challenging as you have indicated.  On Windows, where transparency is possible, then you can stack 2 windows to get the effect of a background image.  That's what Demo_Window_Background_Image.py demonstrates. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/46163555/222898861-8113c107-bd48-4fe5-af78-219ea6f0734d.gif